# Appointment State - EWS Managed API

Tags: outlook, exchangewebservices

I am trying to get all my outlook calendar appointments and meeting using EWS. All appointment are retrieved and I find a property **Appointment.AppointmentState** having different integer values for each item like (0,3,7).

I need to know, what are all the possible values and their description.

I have gone through this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/appointmentstate , but need more information.

Answer (score 1):

If take a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/exchange_server_protocols/ms-oxocal/09861fde-c8e4-4028-9346-e7c214cfdba1 section 2.2.1.10, we could assume, that value is a bitwise combination of:

- 1 = Meeting
- 2 = Received
- 4 = Cancelled

Answer (score 0):

So [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.appointment.appointmentstate?view=exchange-ews-api)  they say: Gets a value that indicates whether the associated object is an appointment, a meeting, a response to a meeting, or a cancelled meeting.

I didn't found the exact indication for each number but you could follow the ordering with the numbers. and compare your values with your calendar to check if it is correct.

Answer (score -1):

1+2=3;1+2+3=7;Bit operation to display

Comment: Please spend a bit more time on the explanation. Please also put code into a code tag